# Install Homebrew packages on macOS Mojave Beta

Tags: homebrew, beta-seed-program, mojave

I am trying to install some dependencies for `flutter`, which requires `homebrew`. The only problem is that homebrew does not install any tools.

For example, if I try both `brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice`, `brew install ideviceinstaller` and `brew install ios-deploy`, it gives me the following error (sometimes it is slightly different) and the tools do not install.

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/davidkeen/Library/Logs/Homebrew/makedepend/05.configure:
checking for rename... yes
checking for fchmod... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for X... configure: error: in `/private/tmp/makedepend-20180609-57475-hh24w0/makedepend-1.0.5':
configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it
is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables X_CFLAGS
and X_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

To get pkg-config, see <http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/>.
See `config.log' for more details

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


Error: You are using macOS 10.14.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.

Error: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.


Error: You are using macOS 10.14.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

How am I meant to install these dependencies on macOS Mojave beta 1?

Please note that `brew install cocoapods` works, so I'm not sure if this is an issue with `homebrew` or `package`?

Comment: The error states that beta versions are not supported.  Can you go back to High Sierra?

Comment: @fsb I can go back to High Sierra as I installed macOS Mojave on a separate partition as I know beta versions can cause bugs/glitches. I wanted to see if I could develop on macOS Mojave. Going back to High Sierra seems like a bodge unless there is no way of getting homebrew to work.I also don't have that much storage on my computer so Installing Xcode 10 and the developer tools on Mojave and High Sierra would use up more storage.

Comment: Can you explain in an edit how you received Mojave beta 1 (unless you’d rather not say)? If you are a registered developer, you need three downloads to make this work. If not, you might be out of luck until command line tools get a more broad release.

Comment: @bmike I got it via a developer account.

Answer (score 8):

```
Error: Your Xcode (9.4) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 10.0 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Mojave.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install
```

This is a different error, however the solution is the same: install the [Xcode 10 Beta](https://developer.apple.com/download/) and then run `xcode-select --install`.

## The Command Line Developer Tools are now available!

First, agree to the invisible license agreement.

[image]

Wait for it to install...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, Brew works happily.

[image]

Comment: If you have access to the beta Xcode, also download and install the beta command line tools and your homebrew will work.

Comment: Please explain *how* to install the beta command line tools, then. I have the Xcode beta, and `xcode-select` doesn't work. Also, isn't that essentially my answer, but without the "it won't work" part?

Comment: Sign in to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ (command line tools are not “featured” so you have to use the see more link at the bottom of the main downloads page). Then pick your os and Xcode and get the installer and run it.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue, there's an easy fix. Head over to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/more, sign in with your Apple ID and install `Command Line Tools (macOS 10.14) for Xcode 10 Beta`.

[image: screenshot of Developer Portal]

Comment: Yeah rudi FTW. Thanks for making this clear instead of letting it be buried in a comment on another post.

Comment: @bmike or my answer, edited almost a month ago (xcode-select works now, and this solution is less convenient)

Comment: @Dev Are you saying that you first need to issue `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app` and then `xcode-select --install` and it will work or is this a case where the local selection of the beta app was irrelevant and the issue was fixed server side to provide an install for a new version that was just released?

Comment: literally just run `xcode-select --install`, it works now

Answer (score 5):

Check `brew doctor`:

```
$ sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app
$ brew install ideviceinstaller
```

Comment: Didn't work, tried both steps.

Answer (score 1):

Picking from the top three answers here, this is what worked for me:

1. go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/more, search for the latest Command Line Tools (macOS 10.14) for Xcode 10 beta (this could be optional as Xcode in the next step should install them anyway);
2. go to https://developer.apple.com/download/, download and install the latest Xcode 10 beta (it is in a .xip archive file, after extracting it you should drop the .app file in your Applications directory);
3. run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app`.

Answer (score -1):

Once you downloaded xcode-beta, you can use `xcode-select --switch` as described in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116645/brew-upgrade-not-working-on-latest-osx-high-sierra-beta-version?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: `xcode-select` comes up with the same error, "not currently available from the Software Update server". I did try `brew` after the switch though, and it gives:

`Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Mojave.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install`