# Why is /usr/include missing? I have Xcode and Command Line Tools installed (Mojave)

Tags: command-line, xcode, development

I just upgraded to Mojave from High Sierra and installed Xcode plus its command line tools and additional tools. Nothing will compile from the terminal, everything says /usr/include is missing!

I checked and ALL the Dev related dirs under /usr are missing!

Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `-isysroot` flag to your compile flags to automatically include the appropriate SDK header directory and avoid the need for the `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` package that will "in a future release, ... no longer be provided."

Examples:

`-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk`

or

`-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk`

You can use `xcrun --show-sdk-path` to find the default SDK path.

You can also use the Xcode or CommandLineTools installed /usr/bin/ versions of clang, clang++, cc, c++, gcc, g++ which are shims calling `xcrun` to invoke the correct tool with the currect SDK and include directories. 
This defaults to CommandLineTools if you have that installed.

You can switch the behavior to use Xcode by:

`$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

or switch back:

`$ sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer`

Comment: You can also use `-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk` if you just want to use the default. However, in most cases, you probably should investigate why the C compiler you're using doesn't pick up the right flags (you probably should be using `clang` from the SDK instead of whatever you're using).

Answer (score 23):

You have to run another step after installing the command line tools:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Why? Apple have introduced a new build tool dance - [system includes are now only kept under a specific SDK's path with Xcode 10 onwards](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes#3035624):

> The Command Line Tools package installs the macOS system headers inside the macOS SDK. Software that compiles with the installed tools will search for headers within the macOS SDK [...] provided by either Xcode [...] or the Command Line Tools [...] depending on which is selected using xcode-select.
>
> [...]
>
> The command line tools will search the SDK for system headers by default. However, **some software may fail to build correctly against the SDK and require macOS headers to be installed in the base system under `/usr/include`** [emphasis added]. If you are the maintainer of such software, we encourage you to update your project to work with the SDK or file a bug report for issues that are preventing you from doing so.  As a workaround, an extra package is provided which will install the headers to the base system. In a future release, this package will no longer be provided. You can find this package at:
>   `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`
>
> To make sure that you're using the intended version of the command line tools, run `xcode-select -s <path to Xcode>` or `xcode select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` after installing.

Comment: Nicholas Smith: How did you find this out?

Comment: I don't even have a Packages directory?!

Comment: I saw it on StackOverflow at some point and it stuck in my head.

Comment: You probably need the command-line tools before attempting this.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/329553/23703).

Comment: You might need to use `sudo` to get this command to work

Comment: If you do this, you're just putting off the inevitable. Apple isn't going to provide even the compatibility package in the next release. Get used to not having /usr/include now. You don't need it.

Comment: This no longer works with Xcode 11.

Answer (score 6):

The "why" is because Apple has deprecated having a /usr/include distinct from the SDK. You shouldn't rely on having it going forward.

The compilers know already to find their includes inside the SDK, so there's no real need for the /usr/include directory any more. You can find the SDK's install directory for the include files using `xcrun --show-sdk-path`

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Except the fact that macOS is (was) unix04 certified.

Comment: Being conformant with the Single Unix Specification or POSIX does not require that /usr/include be present in the file system.

Comment: And yes, it's documented in the SDK documentation.

Comment: the *compilers* might know, but how about various configuration tools, e.g. autoconf. A lot of autoconf macros are written with an assumption that there is something meaningful in /usr, I believe. E.g. would AC_CHECK_HEADER still work?

Comment: Well, MacPorts seems to be doing just fine, even though most of the packages use autoconf. We had less than five broken packages out of many thousands.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik No, most Autoconf macros don't care about /usr/include, and they should not: what matters is that compilers can find them, not where they are.  That's why Autoconf macros don't look for headers on the file system, but compile test files that include them.

Comment: @akim - a lot of macros in Autoconf archive search for things in /opt, etc. Cf. e.g. https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_check_zlib.html#ax_check_zlib
(see `zlib_places="/usr/local /usr /opt/local /sw"` there)

Comment: @DimaPasechnik This macro is badly written.  It should not look for the file, it should check that the include works.  I said "most" :-)

Comment: Could you suggest how it can be improved?

Comment: @Mark Re documentation: this change/issue is mentioned in the [Xcode 10 Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes#3035624) - "However, some software may fail to build correctly against the SDK and require macOS headers to be installed in the base system under /usr/include. [...] As a workaround, an extra package is provided which will install the headers to the base system.". Note the workaround ONLY works for Command Line Tools.

Comment: @Anon you should edit that information into the answer