# How to download Xcode header files for Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: catalina, install, xcode

I'm using Mac OS 10.15.4 Catalina.

macOS Mojave had a known issue whereby users need to download missing Xcode headers.

I have no headers in `/usr/include`

Multiple StackExchange questions and blogposts addressed this question, by recommending users do (roughly) the following:

```
#run installer via command line
sudo installer -pkg
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

- https://silvae86.github.io/2018/07/05/fixing-missing-headers-for-homebrew-in-mac-osx-mojave/
- https://donatstudios.com/MojaveMissingHeaderFiles

However, I cannot find `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/`.

I tried removing the command line tools and re-installing as follows:

```
$ (sudo) rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ xcode-select --install
```

However, I still don't see:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
```

How are these header files made available for Catalina users?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but might be useful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372032/usr-include-missing-on-macos-catalina-with-xcode-11?rq=1

Comment: As noted in that question change  your build system to point to the correct path

Answer (score 1):

After installing Xcode 11.5 on my Catalina Mac, I found many of the standard /usr/include C headers in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/